# What is the form factor of a Dell GXa?

Tags: motherboard, case

I have an old school Dell GXa sitting around.  All the hardware is obviously obsolete but the case is in good shape.  I would consider purchasing a newer motherboard (P4 or better) for it and giving it to one of my friends if I knew what kind of board it took.  I have been looking on Wikipedia in an attempt to see what form factor the motherboard is but I cannot find it.  The bottom half of the board accepts another smaller board (I believe it is called a "daughterboard") which slides in at a 90 degree angle.  Here is a picture of what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Considering the cost of a new case (as little as $25), I wouldn't waste time trying to reuse this one - as one answer below states, the mainboard is custom and not one of the standard sizes used in most generic systems so you're unlikely to find a board worth you time upgrading to.

Comment: I know $25 isn't much, but I just don't want to be wasteful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The large-name computer retailers tend to use custom engineering for things like this for various reasons. You are unlikely to find a replacement motherboard for that machine from anyone but Dell.

Comment: Yeah, I knew it was a possibility that this was a custom board, but I was not 100% sure since I have seen some other old computers that had a similar configuration.